# Julia select element from tuple for each row in array

Tags: arrays, indexing, tuples, julia

I know there has to be a clever way to do this in Julia but I'm stumped. I have a 1d array of tuples and I want to extract the third element from each row of the array. Here is an example of what I'm working with:

```
julia> experArr 20-element Array{(Any,Any,Any),1}:
 (4000,0.97613,1.6e6) 
 (2000,0.97613,800000.0)
 (8000,0.97613,3.2e6) 
 (1000,0.97613,400000.0)
 ...
```

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
julia> experArr[:][3]
```

but that returns the following:

```
julia> experArr[:][3] 
(8000,0.97613,3.2e6)
```

What I want it to return is this:

```
20-element Array{Any,1}:
1.6e6
800000.0
3.2e6
400000.0
...
```

I have tried several other permutations of indexing but I keep only returning a single element. I feel that there is a right way to do this and I'm just missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`experArray[:]` is just a copy of your original array, so that's effectively a no-op. The easiest way to do this is with a comprehension:

```
[ x[3] for x in experArr ]
```

You could also do it with `map`:

```
map(x->x[3], experArr)
```

For the time being, the comprehension version is likely to be faster and have better type behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I just stumbled across the 'map' method but the comprehension way looks more Julia-eque.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially the same as Stefan's answer, but a little more concise, you could broadcast `getfield` over your array:

```
getfield.(experArr, 3)
```